# jQuery: find comments before pre tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-code-prettify

I try to implement like SO code highlight with pretty-print. How to get comment before pre tag?

```
<!-- language: some -->
<pre>
...
```

How to get comment before pre tag?

Comment: Post what you've attempted

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1563-jQuery-Comments-Plug-in-To-Access-HTML-Comments-For-DOM-Templating.htm

Comment: Why was this closed, it is a valid and useful question. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires you to loop through the nodes and check the [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) and read its nodeValue. An element is a nodeType of 1 and a comment is a nodeType of 8.

**HTML:**

```
<p>Apple</p>
<!-- language: some -->
<pre id="one">One</pre>


<!-- language: someOther -->
<pre id="two">two</pre>


<pre id="three">three</pre>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var pres = $("pre");
pres.each(
    function() {
        var prevSibling = this.previousSibling;
        var nodeValue = null;
        while (prevSibling && prevSibling.nodeType!==1) {
            if (prevSibling.nodeType === 8) {
                nodeValue = prevSibling.nodeValue;   
            }
            prevSibling = prevSibling.previousSibling;
        }        
        console.log(this.innerHTML, nodeValue);
    }
);
```

**Example:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2D7EY/)

Answer (score 0):

<del>Most web browsers completely ignore comments. Instead, try to do something like this</del>

Even if it's possible to read comments on a page, I believe any of the following approaches would be better because comments should be separate from code.

```
<pre class="language">
```

or

```
<pre data-language="language">
```

So then you can access it with

```
$(".language")
```

or

```
$("pre[data-language=language]")
```

Comment: No they do not, you just know how to look for them!